# PHP errors when closing while loop outside closing tag and using Html alongside

Tags: php, while-loop

I have searched and stumbled upon many question like this. But that did not answer my question. Therefore, I am asking it again here. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    if(isset($_GET['view'])) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts order by 1 DESC";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        while(mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
        $id = $row['Post_id'];
        $title = $row['Post_title'];
        $date = $row['Post_date'];
        $author = $row['Post_author'];
        $content = $row['Post_content'];
?>
    <table width="800" align="center" border="5">
            <tr>
                   <td align="center" colspan="9"><h1>View all Posts</h1></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
   <?php
        } 
   } 
   ?>
```

Problem is with last line `<?php } } ?>` The instructor whom I am following is doing exactly like this. His code is working perfectly fine. But mine gives error,"Undefined variable row at line 27, 28, 29, 30". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error message text? Also, is the code from those lines visible in your question? If so, which lines are they?

Comment: `while(mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {` -> `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {` maybe ? I think you missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `$row` in your while loop to iterate in each record from your query:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should define `$row` variable.

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
        if(isset($_GET['view'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts order by 1 DESC";
            $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
            $id = $row['Post_id'];
            $title = $row['Post_title'];
            $date = $row['Post_date'];
            $author = $row['Post_author'];
            $content = $row['Post_content'];
        ?>

    <table width="800" align="center" border="5">
            <tr>
                   <td align="center" colspan="9"><h1>View all Posts</h1></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
                            <?php } } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {

//Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
    if(isset($_GET['view'])) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts order by 1 DESC";
        $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
        $id = $row['Post_id'];
        $title = $row['Post_title'];
        $date = $row['Post_date'];
        $author = $row['Post_author'];
        $content = $row['Post_content'];
?>
    <table width="800" align="center" border="5">
            <tr>
                   <td align="center" colspan="9"><h1>View all Posts</h1></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
   <?php
        } 
   } 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Because you did not defined the array $row. You have to define 
$row= array(); before using it. like below

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
        if(isset($_GET['view'])) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM posts order by 1 DESC";
            $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
             $row= array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
            $id = $row['Post_id'];
            $title = $row['Post_title'];
            $date = $row['Post_date'];
            $author = $row['Post_author'];
            $content = $row['Post_content'];
        ?>
<table width="800" align="center" border="5">
            <tr>
                   <td align="center" colspan="9"><h1>View all Posts</h1></td>
            </tr>
                </table>
                            <?php } } ?>
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Define $row variable.

`while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))`